# Stop the sorting in datatable js when resizing the table header

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-events

I am resizing the table header using jQuery UI's resizable method

```
$("th").resizable();
```

After I am leaving the mouse, it is firing the sorting for datatable. I want to stop sorting when I am resizing.

```
$("th").on("resizestop", function (event, ui) { event.stopImmediatePropagation();});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rYtxh/306/)

Any help is appreciated.